# IE8 Compatability View Mode for Intranet Sites Group Policy

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, group-policy, active-directory, internet-explorer-8

Is there a group policy to disable this checkbox, I don't want compatibility view mode to be allowed on my network at all for anything or for any site. I don't even understand why Microsoft added it. It doesn't even work the same as IE7, instead of having to support 3 IE browsers now, Microsoft made it that 4 need supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 1 of 2 things I believe:

The GPO policies are located in:

Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Compatibility View

(both user and computer settings have them depending on how you want to deploy them)

You can either turn off compatibility mode completely for the browser:  "Turn off compatibility mode"

Or you can disable compatibility mode just for intranet sites: "Turn on Internet Explorer Standards Mode for Local Intranet"

See here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197

> Turn on Internet Explorer Standards Mode for Local Intranet: This setting disables Compatibility View (enables Standards Mode) for all intranet Web sites.